# Drupal site links suddenly open in new tab?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Ok, first thing first, I am not Drupal expert. I was tasked to backup and migrate Drupal site from one hosting to the other. I have done exactly that, everything works, but problem is that every internal link opens in new tab suddenly? What could be the cause of that? Thank you, I have googled around for this issue but came empty handed.

Comment: Does every anchor tag have a `target="_blank"` attribute? then it might come from a global config or a theme override, if not I would try to disable javascript.

Comment: @n0tting Yes it does, I suspected as much that it is the webhosting global override, thanks for confirming that